# Pass by reference in perl

Tags: perl

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (1,2,3,4,5);
my $v = 1;

sub by_ref 
{
    my ($array_ref,$v) = @_;  
    @$array_ref = (0,0,0);
    print "Array inside by_ref: @$array_ref\n"; 
}

by_ref(\@array,$v);
print "Array changed: @$array\n";
```

I'm passing `@array` by reference(I'm assuming I'm doing it right). I want the changes made in the sub routine on `@array`be reflected in the calling sub routine. I don't know where I have gone wrong. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to change the list?  You also don't use `$v`.

Comment: Works for me, I get three zeroes for both print statements. The last one should just be "@array" rather than "@$array".

Comment: yes i'm trying to change the list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are printing the array reference outside the subroutine too, which is wrong. The scope of array reference is limited to the subroutine only.

So you should change your last line to print only `@array` not `@$array`.

Like:

`print "Array changed: @array\n";`

Comment: Output: `Array inside by_ref: 0 0 0
Array changed: 0 0 0`

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble. :)

Comment: [http://ideone.com/7dir1](http://ideone.com/7dir1) I'm getting an error when I do this.

Comment: That's not how you access element from array reference. Use `@$array_ref[1]`. http://ideone.com/U1lqi. You need to study more about references in perl. Start from here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Comment: You're welcome :) `perldoc` is awesome. You can refer it whenever you need to learn something in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Just change to

```
print "Array changed: @array\n";
```

and it should be ok